# I can't reach the time in "Can it be 0?"

Tags: algorithm, time, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to make a program where, giving a number 'n', and a vector of numbers 'v', you have to try to make the 'n' zero by summing, subtracting or not using, the remaining numbers in 'v'.

This is my algorithm:

```
bool ALG(const VectorI& v, IteratorV it, int need, int left)
{
    if(it == v.end())  // No more
        return false;
    if (need == *it)  // If I find what I need
        return true;

    if (left < need)   // If it's impossible 
        return false;
    else
    {
        int i = *it;

        if(i == left) // If I'm the last one
        {
            if(abs(need)==abs(left) )   
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }


        if( i == 0 )
            return (ALG(v, ++it, need, left));

        IteratorV aux = ++it;
        if( ALG(v, aux, need-i, left-i) || // sum it
           ALG(v, aux, need+i, left-i) ||  // subt it
           ALG(v, aux, need, left-i)     // don't use it
           )
            return true;
          else
              return false;
    }

}
```

But it takes too long when inputs are big. Anyone can help me to make it faster? (or just another way).

EDIT:
So, I call it like this:

ALG(v,v.begin(),random_number,sum_of(v));

So, I point to the first element. The parameter 'left' is the sum of the values from Iterator it to the end. Everytime I take a decision about what to do with the number pointed by the iterator( sum, subtract or nothing), I run the iterator 1 position (cause I have seen this number).
Then, depending on what I want to do, I change 'need' in one way or other (if I want to sum the number, 'need+*it', and so on) but what is left always change, due to I have taken a decision about the pointed number.

The vector 'v' has 100 numbers (max), and the sum of all of them is 1000(max).

Comment: I imagine you're calling it like so:  `ALG(v,v.begin(),0,0)`?  On the line commented `//don't use it`, shouldn't that be `left`, not `left-i`?  I'm not clear on what `left` is for.

Comment: Every number I'm taking a decision about has "left-i", due to I run the iterator one position. But, the difference in that, as I'm not gonna use it, I don't change the number that I need (cause I don't sum or subt anything)

Comment: Is this a variation on the subset sum problem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: I didn't understand your response, user.  How do you call it?  `ALG(v,v.begin(), 0, 0)?`?  What is a "left-i"?

Comment: The problem is NP hard, so you're not going to get a general fast solution here, but there may be properties of the input data that you can use. For example, that they're all small integers. Without the additional information about the input data, the question is hard to answer.

Comment: @JimMischel I don't know. I think Subset Sum Problem only allows you to sum the numbers, but it cannot subtract two of them, so, if I want to get 3 from the set: {4,1} he will never reach the goal. If I'm wrong, please let me know it!

Comment: That's why I said "variation on." It looks to me like the subset sum problem with an added twist: you can either add or subtract.